# How to prevent warnings on Android device or Emulator

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, genymotion

I have made an application in `react-native` and it is working fine but when I start my application or reload it shows me yello colored warnings at the bottom which can be dismissed no doubt. But I want to disable or prevent my application from these warnings.

[image]

Any clues?

Comment: from what you describe it sounds like a SnackBar, just remove the code. Share the screenshot and code for the initial activity.

Comment: These warnings such as `undefined is not an object` comes if you just create a basic application with react-native